# All UNexisting files and folders redirecting except for those with php extension

Tags: php, nginx, easyphp, nginx-config

I use the following directive for my application:

```
location / {
    root  "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www";
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?param=$uri;
}
```

Which redirects all the unexisting files and folders to index.php with $_GET parameter of url, except for the php files where i get the following error:

> No input file specified.

Is there a workaround to make this work with the .php extension?

Comment: requests to `index.php` work fine?

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko yes, just .php files that dont exist are not redirected by try_files fallback, which is index

Comment: you can use this solution https://serverfault.com/a/219081